# How can I align JLabel and JTextField vertically?

Tags: java, jlabel, jtextfield

I'm still a beginner in Java so I'm sorry if I'll make any mistakes but, my question is how can I align JLabel and JTextField so that they're aligned vertically like this:

username: ____________

password: ____________

(I'm still a student learning the basics of Java.)

Comment: You forgot to add what you tried

Comment: Practice Swing layouts

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2

Comment: Did my answer help you to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't say what you've tried and which IDE you are using here a two examples

### NetBeans designer

Select the components which you want to equalize and right click on of them if you are using NetBeans. Like this: (I'm using Free Design layout)

[image: NetBeans designer same size]

---

### Code

You could do it on your own with [GroupLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html). Add the labels which you want to equalize to an array. (follow the link for a tutorial)

```
Component[] labels = new Component[]{jLabel1, jLabel2};
```

Then call `linkSize()`

```
layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, labels);
layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, labels);
```

I could go more into detail, but only if you tell me what you've tried and which IDE you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridLayout

```
` 
setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));  
  add(new JLabel("username:"));
  add(new JTextFeild(" ",10));
  add(new JLabel("password:");
  add(new JPasswordFeild(" " , 10);
```

`